# Authentication via AES

Tags: http, authentication, encryption, cryptography

I am still quite new to cryptography, so please excuse any rookie mistakes. I am shure this has been asked a couple of times, but I have no idea what to search for.

So, I have a server, which receives commands over http from my smartphone. Currently everything is encrypted using AES with a password, which can be set in the server's config.

The problem is that, when someone intercepts my requests, he cannot decrypt the commands, but he can resend the encrypted command to my server.

Two solutions I imagine are:

- encrypt a timestamp within the command, so they are invalid after a period of time, but with the disadvantage that still (within that period) the commands can be resent.
- the server sends some random stuff to the client, which must encrypt that and send the encrypted stuff back (I think that will kill my http approach)

I am shure there are better ways (maybe another algorithm?), any help is welcome.

Again, I don't have much experience with cryptography and programming is just a hobby :D

Comment: How about throwing HTTPS at the problem?

Comment: How would I authenticate a https client? I've only heard of that for servers.

Comment: Authenticate the server via a certificate, then send the password in plain over HTTPS.

Comment: Ok, I will try pure ssl as suggested in [atk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19254164/625623) first, as it seems to be the easier way. Anyways thank you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do not try to reinvent secure communication.  SSL and SSH are two very widely used, and very good protocols for secure communication, both of which will address replay, as well as many other security issues that you've not yet thought of (re-ordering, removing messages, inserting messages from one place into another, etc).

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that. Is it possible to use SSL with passwords or do I have to use certificate files instead?

Comment: Yes, SSL has a password authentication mode.  I haven't personally used it, but I know several folks who have used it.

Comment: Also, as in the comments to the original question, you can do server authentication with SSL and client authentication in the protocol running atop SSL.  That's the way web browsers typically do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need both encryption and authentication.

As stated by others, please only use SSL (HTTPS) for encryption for HTTP requests. SSL is exceptional for encryption. SSL can do authentication but there are better solutions for authentication of users from smartphones.

For authentication of the user, there are many options. For smartphone connections I suggest you also not invent your own authentication protocol and use tried and tested solutions such as [OpenID](http://openid.net/) and [OATH](http://oauth.net/). There are many libraries that support this. Using such protocols opens the possibility of authenticating users using their existing Google, Facebook, Twitter accounts etc.